# Clean way to restore disabled pipe before saving model

Tags: python, spacy

I do some NER training with spacy.
I had follow the example and use

```
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
  optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
```

My training are quite long so I need to save the model often at different iterations. I use `nlp.to_disk(outdir)` to save the model but it save in its current state: with disabled pipes.

Is there a clean way to save it with others pipe (maybe by using a copy of the model and restoring pipe to it?) or I need to use a code like this:

```
while i:
  disabled = nlp.disable_pipes('tagger', 'parser')
  optimizer = nlp.begin_training(gold_tuples)
  disabled.restore()
  nlp.to_disk(outdir)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have should work. Or you can use `nlp.disable_pipes()` as a context manager. Is there a reason either of those are unsatisfying?

Comment: Thanks again @syllogism_. I was thinking that because begin_training() was generating an optimizer it would be better to keep the same for the whole process.

Comment: Or can I generate the optimizer first and then disable / restoring pipe ?